# PowerShell Opens Off Screen

Tags: windows, powershell

I changed my monitor configuration, and now PowerShell appears off screen. I moved it back on screen with alt-space > move, but it opens off screen every time. How do I get it to remember its position?

Comment: Hi, have you played with the Window Position options in Properties > Layout ?

Comment: Ccleaner has an option to reset this, if you are willing to install it and try. Be careful and read ALL the options before running the cleanup or you will delete all your internet history, for example.

Comment: @sodawillow I went to the position options and checked "Let system position window". Worked great, thanks! Seems like a dumb question now, but every other site I found was scripting related, so I guess I won't delete this :P

Comment: @Alex weirdly, I had to *uncheck* that box. It was already checked, and after changing the x/y position, it continued to open with the bottom off my screen. Unchecking that box used my input instead of however windows was deciding to position it (the problem to begin with). Just adding my experience!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems the Window Position options in Properties > Layout did the trick for OP : ).